# Diamond inheritance with additional class copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So I was wondering lately what the copy constructor of an class will look if we have a base class `A` that is being virtually inherited by `B` and `C`, where `B` and `C` are inherited by `D` and `D` is inherited by `E`.

[image]

So I am a bit confused. Should `D`'s copy constructor still have the base class's (`A`) constructor in its initializing list or is that the job of `E` now? Am I correct that `E` could inherit `D` non-virtually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicitly generated copy constructor works fine, but if you wanted to explicitly write it yourself it could look like:

```
D(D const &o): A(o), B(o), C(o) {}

E(E const &o): A(o), D(o) {}
```

For initialization purposes, virtual base classes behave as if they are a direct base of the most-derived object.  Any initializer in a subobject is ignored (e.g. in my code for `E`, the initialization `D(o)` actually does not initialize the `A` despite the fact that `A` is listed in `D`'s copy constructor).

This is the same whether or not `E` inherits `D` virtually.

[Link to further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993429/why-does-using-a-virtual-base-class-change-the-behavior-of-the-copy-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `A` should still be in the initializing list and `E` does not need to inherit `D` virtually. The order of construction should be:

```
A() --> B() --> C() --> D()
```